# Notification not showing in the status bar

Tags: android, notifications

I am using the below code to show the notification, but nothing shows up.
I tried using the notification channel also. still it is not working.
I am testing in an Oreo device.

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "notify_001");
    Intent ii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, ii, 0);

    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    bigText.bigText("sdsd");
    bigText.setBigContentTitle("Today's Bible Verse");
    bigText.setSummaryText("Text in detail");

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Your Title");
    mBuilder.setContentText("Your text");
    mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    mBuilder.setLargeIcon(null);
    mBuilder .setSubText("");
    mBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mBuilder.setStyle(bigText);


    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("notify_001",
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());

I am testing in an Oreo device.

Comment: Did you try with another device different than Oreo? Show us where this code is being called

Comment: Its called in the main activity

Comment: Its working in other phones